# How can we find such a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$. For $0_{\mathbb{R}^n}\neq x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we define the map $$\sigma_x:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, \ v\mapsto v-2\frac{x\cdot v}{x\cdot x}x$$

This map is linear and it holds that $\sigma_x\in \text{Sym}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\sigma_x=\sigma_x^{-1}$.

For all $v,w\in \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $v\cdot w=\sigma_x(v)\cdot \sigma_x(w)$.

Let $n=2$. Determine a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\sigma_v=\sigma_a$, where $\sigma_a$ is 
the reflection on the straight line through the origin, where $a$ describes the angle between the straight line and the positive $x$-axis.

How can we find such a vector? Do we use the matrix of the map of $\sigma_a$ ?

Comment: Note that  $\sigma_{x}$ fixes  $\{x\}^{\perp}$. Actually, $\sigma_{x}$ is the reflection across the hyperplane $\{x\}^{\perp}$. So I guess $v=(-\sin a,\cos a)$ will work in your problem.

Comment: What is meant by $\{x\}^{\perp} $? And wlhow did you find this vector? @ThomasShelby

Comment: $\{x\}^{\perp}=\{v\mid x\cdot v=0\}$.